# Convert Office Documents to XPS File Programatically or Third Party tool

Tags: c#, office-interop, xps

I have an application that i am working on which needs actually a file preview in a preview pane so because of that after searching a lot on google found that there are some ways to actually preview the files using PreviewHandlers but management does not want that to be a solution.

So without that we can only be left with converting the documents to XPS and use them to preview in DocumentViewer where all the tools are available.

For PDF file Acrobat provides a COM component that is fine. The problem here is i am able to convert doc,docx files to xps to show them as preview but not able to convert anyother files to xps.

Or a library that converts all files to pdf that also is fine.

if someone has faced this before or know the solution/Third party library that does the work to convert the documents then the help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Microsoft [2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7). Chect out [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranab/archive/2008/09/24/convert-office-documents-docx-pptx-pub-into-pdf-programmatically.aspx) example